# Combining 'let' and 'letfn'

Tags: clojure

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for combing mutiple `let` and `letfn` statements inside a function body.
Local functions should be able to call each other recursively:

```
(defn func [input] (
       let [local-var 3]
       letfn [(do-local [a local]
             (println a))]  
       (do-local input local-var)))
```

As it works fine for isolated local variable or function definition, combining `let` and `letfn` results in a compilation error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/letfn
```

Is there a way to get around that issue?

Edit:

Using `(letfn [(local-var [_] (3))])` as factory function might still be another option, although it is just a workaround.

Edit 2:

I corrected the syntax error by placing `letfn` into a seperate inner scope,  according to

`(let ... (letfn ... ( execute functions)))`

```
(defn func [input] (
           let [local-var 3]
           (letfn [(do-local [a local]
                 (println a))]  
           (do-local input local-var))))
```

Edit 3:

Switched to usage of `let` for local function definition, according to User  [xificurC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688998/xificurc) suggestion.

```
(defn func [input] (
           let [local-var 3
                do-local (fn [a local] (println a)) ]  
           (do-local input local-var)))
```

Comment: Check your parens first. You have a syntax error.

Comment: Fixed it! Error message remains the same.

Comment: You miss the parens around letfn - see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/letfn

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand here. I am used to put `let` or `letfn` into one scope together with the function body. You mean that `let` and `letfn` have to be placed into a seperated scope now?

Comment: `let` and `letfn` are separate macros and they have to be placed into separated scope.

Comment: Your closing paren for the `letfn` is still wrong. `letfn` wraps a form, where the functions exist.  It's not like `defn` that places them in a ns.

Comment: I corrected the mistake, see my edit 2. However, opening nested scopes is not the most intuitive solution to me.

Comment: No, you havent.  You should really look into an editor, that shows such problems. E.g. paredit automatically ballances the parens.  And most editors will at least mark errors in un-even parens.

Comment: Not every paren opens a new scope, although in this case both let and letfn do. If it's not intuitive it suggests you don't have a lispy background. To guide your intuition, `let` just binds values whereas `letfn` allows for mutually recursive calls without the need to declare them forward, so it really is a different beast. If you don't need mutual recursion (which you usually don't) you could bind the function in the `let` as well as `(let [do-local (fn [a] (println a))])`, avoiding the nesting.

Comment: @xificurC TIL that to recurse w/ local functions, use `letfn`.

Comment: @AaronBell recursion of a single function can be done without `letfn`, for tail calls you can use `recur` and for non-tail calls you can give the function a name, i.e. `(fn self [x] (+ x (if (odd? x) x (self (dec x)))))`. What `letfn` solves is 2+ functions that call each other, e.g. `odd?` defined via `even?` and `even?` defined via `odd?`. Since both need the other first you can't define them sequentially, which is where you need `declare` for global functions and `letfn` for local ones.